# Penalizing false negatives in a binary classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, classification, loss-function

I am trying to penalize the False Negatives more than False Positives in a binary classification problem.

The custom loss function looks like: inspired from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2115#issuecomment-204060456)

```
def w_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, weights):
    nb_cl = len(weights)
    final_mask = K.zeros_like(y_pred[:, 0])
    y_pred_max = K.max(y_pred, axis=1)
    y_pred_max = K.reshape(y_pred_max, (K.shape(y_pred)[0], 1))
    y_pred_max_mat = K.cast(K.equal(y_pred, y_pred_max), K.floatx())
    for c_p, c_t in product(range(nb_cl), range(nb_cl)):
        final_mask += (weights[c_t, c_p] * y_pred_max_mat[:, c_p] * y_true[:, c_t])
    return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true) * final_mask
```

Following are the weights being passed to the weights param in the above function:

```
w_array = np.ones((2,2))
w_array[1,0] = 2.5 # penalizing FN
w_array[0,1] = 2.5 # penalizing FP
```

In my understanding, first line is penalizing the FN and the second one is penalizing the FP. When I try to run this code, the number of FN/FP is pretty much the same as in the case with equal weights as shown below

```
w_array = np.ones((2,2))
#w_array[1,0] = 2.5 # penalizing FN
#w_array[0,1] = 2.5 # penalizing FP
```

FOLLOW UP: If i simply comment out the second assignment in w_array, does it mean I am only penalizing the FN and not the FP. What is the importance of `final_mask` here?

Function call and usage:

```
loss = lambda y_true, y_pred: w_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, weights=w_array)

classifier.compile(optimizer = sgd, loss = loss, metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Your two weight examples are identical?

Comment: @Prune thanks  for a quick reply.
 I tried `w_array[1,0] = n` and `w_array[0,1] = 3n` still I am getting the same answer, when n = 1, 2. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not yet; you didn't give us a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for reproduction and experimentation.

Comment: @Prune sorry for that. I will update it. New to SO, not very experienced with making a question reproducible yet.